# Infragistics Ultragrid - do not move below row when selecting right most column

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Is there any way to force Infragistics Ultragrid to do not move below row when pressing right arrow key on last column ?

eg having below table, being in cell with "C" value (COL_1, row 1) - if I press right arrow key it moves me to below row (D value), while I woudld like stay in same row, same cell (as Ive reached 'end' of row)

```
   COL_A | COL_B | COL_C
1    A      B        C
2    D      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyDown` event for the UltraGrid might be used to implement this functionality too:

```
private void ultraGrid1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right && sender is UltraGrid ug)
    {
        if ((ug.CurrentState & UltraGridState.CellLast) == UltraGridState.CellLast)
            e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Navigation in the grid is a result of default [KyeActionMapping](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid%7Einfragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragrid%7Ekeyactionmappings). What you can do is remove mapping for Right and add a new one preventing last cell state like this:

```
// Get the mappings related to Right key and remove them from KeyActionMappings
var mappings = this.ultraGrid1.KeyActionMappings.GetActionMappings(Keys.Right, 1, 0);
foreach (var mapping in mappings)
{
    this.ultraGrid1.KeyActionMappings.Remove(mapping);
}

// Add new KeyActionMappings
this.ultraGrid1.KeyActionMappings.Add(
    new GridKeyActionMapping(
        Keys.Right, 
        UltraGridAction.NextCell,
        UltraGridState.CellLast,
        UltraGridState.Cell,
        SpecialKeys.AltCtrl,
        0,
        true));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply - this works but only partially - now when I move to last column and then press once more right arrow key Im focusing next control, while I want to stop in same cell (so I can press left arrow to move back)